# Is there a GUI to handle LVM and software RAID operations?

Tags: lvm, gui, software-rec, software-raid, free-software

Are there any [free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) graphical tools to manage advanced Linux storage schemes such as
[software RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Software-based)
and
[LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) arrays
in a similar fashion to how
[GParted](https://gparted.org/) handles partitions?

Unfortunately, it seems most Linux distributions don't come with such tools installed.

There is, for example, [GNOME Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks), but it doesn't have the capability to do this any longer.

What tools are available that fit my criteria?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check [Blivet](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Blivet) GUI ([`blivet-gui`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Blivet-gui)), it's the old [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) LVM and RAID management tool (there are no replacement I am aware of) and is released under [GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html).

[image: blivet-gui]

It includes all the RAID and LVM operations that you would otherwise expect from GParted (creation, deletion, mount, encryption). It also supports basic LUKS handling.

If it's not packaged on your GNU/Linux distribution, building instructions are on project's repository.

Another possible solution is [kvpm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kvpm/), which currently requires a couple more manual dependencies to build for end-users.