# is there a graphical LVM tool... system-config-lvm?

Tags: lvm, gui

like with `gparted`, is there a graphical gui for LVM to facilitate `vgcreate` and `lvcreate` ?

I am in RHEL7.9 x86-64,  have the RHEL repo's and EPEL and rpmfusion;

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/review-gui-lvm-tools   mentions `system-config-lvm` but I am not finding it, does it still exist for RHEL 7.9 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a GUI to handle LVM and software RAID operations?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698642/is-there-a-gui-to-handle-lvm-and-software-raid-operations)

Comment: falls short, I have same question basically, and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/s1-system-config-lvm mentions `system-config-lvm` so I'd like that if possible

Comment: https://fedoramagazine.org/manage-your-partitions-like-in-anaconda-with-blivet-gui/    comment : `This was the missing piece of software to replace the suddenly discontinued system-config-lvm.`

Comment: deja vu : https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=70274   I'd use blivet-gui but seems very difficult to acquire, it sounds like it was beta that never caught on

Comment: My 2cts : If you need a gui for very low level software control then… : Stay away from that software.

Comment: eh i figured out `vgcreate` and `lvcreate` so i guess i'll give up on the gui part

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user commented that they are giving up on finding the exact type of tool they asked about.